# Firestore.settings() requires one argument yet all arguments are optional in docs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings), all arguments of `firebase.firestore.Settings()` function are optional. Yet when I call it without argument I get this error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Function Firestore.settings() requires 1
>   argument, but was called with 0 arguments.

How to fix this issue?

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  const config = {
    apiKey: '...',
    authDomain: '...',
    databaseURL: '...',
    projectId: '...',
    storageBucket: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...'
  }
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
  firebase.firestore().settings()
}
```

Comment: Would you like the edit the question to show the exact code that doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking at the [Settings class properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings#properties_1).

The `settings(Settings)` method documentation of `Firestore` class instance, that accepts a Settings object, is located [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore.html#settings).

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    const config = {
        apiKey: '...',
        authDomain: '...',
        databaseURL: '...',
        projectId: '...',
        storageBucket: '...',
        messagingSenderId: '...'
    }

    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)
    const firestore = firebase.firestore(firebaseApp)
    firestore.settings({
        //Settings properties
        //cacheSizeBytes: 0,
        //host: '',
        //ssl: true
    })
}
```